# How do you edit the 'hosts' file in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you edit hosts file on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/49118/how-do-you-edit-hosts-file-on-windows-7)

I need to edit the `hosts` file so that I could restrict some sites from opening. I have tried to open it and edit it but when I save it, Admin privileges error is displayed. Even with admin privileges it doesn't allow me to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has posted a workaround in a support article, 
["Modify the Hosts file or the Lmhosts file in Windows Vista and Windows 7"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923947).

Comment: I've just edited Karan's answer to clarify that despite the unfortunate title, this is a link to a workaround, not to an article claiming it simply can't be done.

Comment: Ugh, yes, the article provides a workaround. The title is to be interpreted not as "you cannot do it", but as "you cannot do it normally, so here's how". Also, thanks for the edit, Nicole! :)

Comment: cool, just a thought, you can create the link to say anything you want of course.  Might be a good idea to just change the link text :)

Comment: @Josh: Yep, I know that. Was in a bit of a hurry and so it actually just failed to occur to me that the original title could be misinterpreted. Will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 6):

Open up Notepad with Administrator rights.
Then open hosts file with Notepad and you can edit and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Run your editor as administrator. That way it has permissions to write to the file.

Alternatively: Edit the file, save it in an alternative place and copy ot as administrator.