# How to edit the hosts file in MS Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hosts-file

I am looking for a step by step instruction on how to edit the hosts file in MS Windows 10. To edit this file you need to have admin rights, which I have.

I tried via MS Windows Explorer. This tool can be started as admin by navigating to C:\Windows and right click on explorer.exe. It is not possible to run as admin from normal menu.

But when you navigate to a file and then open for example using notepad.exe you loose admin privileges.

Is there still an easy way to edit hosts file in MS Windows 10? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you edit hosts file on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/49118/how-do-you-edit-hosts-file-on-windows-7).  How you edit the hosts file on Windows 10 is identical to how you edit it on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

#### I am looking for instructions on how to edit the hosts file in MS Windows 10

> 1. Press the Windows key.
> 2. Type Notepad in the search field.
> 3. In the search results, right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
> 4. From Notepad, open the following file: c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
> 5. Make the necessary changes to the file.
> 6. Click File > Save to save your changes.

Source [/etc/hosts on Windows](https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/18b10a14b2deb214dc4ce43a2d2e2992)